# Which is faster: a bank with five lines of ten or one line of fifty?

Tags: probability, statistics, variance, means

I'm working on a probability question with mean and variance.

> Let's say that I have two banks. They are identical in every way,
>   except that bank A has five lines with ten people and bank B has one
>   line with fifty people. There are five tells in each bank.
>
> In bank A, each of those tellers is dedicated to serving one line and
>   in bank B, the teller serves the next available customer. Which has a
>   faster average wait time and longer variance wait time?

I understand the first part of the question. The average wait time is the same because it is, in your line, the time to help each customer * the number of customers / the number of bank tellers.

For bank A, that's time * 10 / 1 and for bank B, it's time * 50 / 5.

I don't understand the second part of the question though. Intuitively, I think that bank B should have a longer standard deviation for wait time since there are more people and you have a greater chance at getting extreme outliers, or customers who take much longer than anyone else.

Comment: A single (longer) line served by 5 tellers is (at least to me) intuitively faster overall than five separate (shorter) lines with a single teller each. Consider, for instance, what happens if all customers have a 1 minute serving time, except for a single person who takes an hour to serve. If he's in front of the single long line, the others will barely notice he's there. If he's in front of one of the short lines, everyone behind him will still be there waiting long after all the other lines are cleared.

Comment: Assuming the time to help comes from a normal distribution, then doesn't it fall evenly in both directions? You can have people who take a long time but you'll also have people who take an incredibly short time.

Comment: Additionally - isn't the effect the same since you have five tellers in the long line?

Comment: Think of it this way: With the separate lines setup, you may have one line which is completely cleared and one line where there are still people waiting. The people waiting in the second line could've cut down their waiting time if they were allowed to go to the other teller. With the single line, this utilisation of all five tellers for as long as possible happens naturally.